# Variable not being returned from Ajax Javascript (though javascript receives it)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm receiving the variable to JavaScript, but not getting it back in PHP, and I think Its not being coded correctly in the JavaScript:

```
function glitch_player_display(mix_name) {
  alert(mix_name);
  throb.start();
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxglitch_playerajax.ajaxurl,
    data: {
      action: 'ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler',
      mix_name: mix_name
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
      throb.stop();
      var showglitchplayer = '#showglitchplayer';
      jQuery(showglitchplayer).html('');
      jQuery(showglitchplayer).append(data);
    },
    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

This is the PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler', 'ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler', 'ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler' );

function ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler($arguments){
  var_dump($arguments);
}
```

returns empty.

Thanks and have a great one.

Comment: What player are you using? What are you trying to do in detail? Please let us know all the details ;)

Comment: @Sven I'm actually sending the variable to a python script. Echonest Remix. It's pretty sweet.

Comment: most of the code is posted here [on gitHub](https://github.com/MikeiLL/devil)

Comment: Try to change `url: ajaxglitch_playerajax.ajaxurl` to `url: ajaxglitch_playerajax`; I'm getting the request, but there seems to be another problem...

Comment: that causes a "not found" js error... and $arguments is still empty back in php.

Comment: What does your action hook look like for the PHP ajax function?

Comment: Okay, one more try: are you getting any results for `var_dump($_POST['mix_name']);` ?

Comment: i am getting value in $_POST! `[action] => ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler
    [mix_name] => 36fa7df803`

Comment: @josh is this the action hook ya mean: `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler', 'ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AJAX callback doesn't take any parameters, you have to get them from the request using `$_GET`/`$_POST`/`$_REQUEST` (depending on how you have your javascript set up). This means that to get get `mix_name` from your `POST` you would use `$_POST['mix_name']`. Including the `add_action( 'wp_ajax_...` calls from your code would be good if you have future questions as well, I had to go to the GitHub page to see how you had it set up - you're also missing single quotes around `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajaxglitch_player_enqueuescripts' );` which PHP can figure out, but it will try it as a constant first. This is what the config should look like:

```
function ajaxglitch_player_enqueuescripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajaxglitch_player', glitch_player_URL.'/js/glitch_player.js', array('jquery'));
    // access ajax url on the front end as ajaxglitch_playerajax.ajaxurl
    wp_localize_script( 'ajaxglitch_player', 'ajaxglitch_playerajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajaxglitch_player_enqueuescripts' );

// front end ajax handler
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler', 'ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler' );
// admin ajax handler
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler', 'ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler' );

function ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler(){
    $mix_name = isset( $_POST['mix_name'] )? $_POST['mix_name'] : false;
    var_dump( "The mix_name is $mix_name" ); // this will probably break the AJAX response
    error_log( "The mix_name is $mix_name" ); // write it to the error_log too.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, amigo. tripplesharp! I'm planning on having more questions in the future. And soon. I would only want to write out to the error log for dev purposes though, correct?

Comment: That's a personal preference - one downside is that it can be hard to clean up all of your debug statements once you are ready to move to prod. Another option would be to call your own `my_debug()` function and put the `error_log()` inside it, then control it all with a `if ( $debug )` - you just have to set $debug somewhere.

Comment: As a personal preference I also like to use classes for my plugins to keep the namespace cleaner and allow for shorter action/function names to keep it readable. No AJAX callbacks but it's shorter so you can see the pattern in this plugin I wrote - http://justin.ag/technology/wordpress/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-remote-content-shortcode/ - with `add_action()` for you being like `add_shortcode()` in this plugin.

Comment: So `$debug` would be hardcoded to either true or false? Or would it be aligned with the wordpress `debug` config?

Comment: However you wanted to do it - I would probably use a constant in wp-config.php if I was going to hardcode it. Typically i just go wild and then search the code once I'm done and remove anything that isn't valid.

Comment: I usually end up just echoing everything out or using `function pr($data)
   {
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($data);
       echo "</pre>";
   }` I've been experimenting a little with creating a class as you have done (great post and plugin btw), but seems like it may be a bigger task than I thought. I will probably post another question because I'd like to pass the data to jscript via a simple form instead of a link - so users can input.

Comment: that works, or if you do want to [write objects to the error log](http://justin.ag/technology/writing-to-the-php-error_log-with-var_dump-and-print_r/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14887/discussion-between-mike-ill-and-doublesharp).